# Add a latex code before and after every \newtheorem

Tags: amsthm, hooks

I define a few theorems with `amsthm`'s `\newtheorem`, and I want to prepend and append an `hrule` for each one of them. Currently I do it with

```
\AddToHook{env/〈env name〉/before}{hrule code}
```

and

```
\AddToHook{env/〈env name〉/after}{hrule code}
```

for each and every `\newtheorem`.

Any idea how to make my code more compact so I state the `AddToHook`s only once and not every time I define a new `note` style environment?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{note}% 〈name〉
{3pt}% 〈Space above〉
{3pt}% 〈Space below 〉
{}% 〈Body font〉
{}% 〈Indent amount〉
{\itshape}% 〈Theorem head font〉
{:}% 〈Punctuation after theorem head 〉
{.5em}% 〈Space after theorem head 〉3
{}% 〈Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’ )

\theoremstyle{note}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
  \AddToHook{env/theorem/before}{\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\hrule}
  \AddToHook{env/theorem/after}{\hrule\vspace{\baselineskip}}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
  \AddToHook{env/definition/before}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\par\hrule} % same Hook as above
  \AddToHook{env/definition/after}{\hrule\vspace{\baselineskip}}

\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[chapter]
  \AddToHook{env/remark/before}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\par\hrule} % Those two hooks again
  \AddToHook{env/remark/after}{\hrule\vspace{\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
Some theorems, definitions and remarks appear here.
\end{document}
```

*I am aware of `thmtools` and its `preheadhook` and `postfoothook` keys. But I want to use only `amsthm`.*

Comment: your code doesn't work. There can be a pagebreak between the rule and the theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily achieve that effect using a suitable macro.

```latex
\newcommand*\newtushtheorem[1]{%
  \AddToHook{env/#1/before}{\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\hrule}%
  \AddToHook{env/#1/after}{\hrule\vspace{\baselineskip}}%
  \newtheorem{#1}%
}

\newtushtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtushtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtushtheorem{remark}{Remark}[chapter]
```

---

However, as mentioned in [the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688762/add-a-latex-code-before-and-after-every-newtheorem#comment1708862_688762), note that this way of adding rules may not always behave in the preferred way.